# shadows are showing in unity editor but not on android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am doing a game in unity game engine .
I started developing the game in 4.6 but later on unity 5 get released so i upgraded my project to unity 5 version now my game running on android devices but i have one problem with shadows of game-objects which are showed in unity editor but not on the device.I am not able sort out this problem. I am also using NGUI for game user interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just changed the quality settings to fastest 
you can find that option in edit->project settings->quality->then in right side you will see levels for different platforms set it to fastest 
this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Check your quality settings (Edit/Project Settings/Quality) and make sure the default quality level for Android has shadows enabled.

Comment: no, i check by doing this but no shadows are coming on device

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and then discovered that it was a limitation of the device I was using.  On a slightly older Asus Nexus 7 tablet, shadows wouldn't appear, no matter what I did in the Quality Settings.  I switched to a Lenovo Yoga 2 tablet and everything worked fine.